# Resolving ID3 tags from chosen audio file in Android

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, id3

I am trying to resolve the ID3 tag information of an selected audio file

I am starting an Intent to let the user choose a file

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
            intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
            intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent_upload, 1);
        }
```

in onActivityResult I try to parse the content Uri to the real file path.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.i("Yolo", data.getData().getPath());

                String realPath = getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), uri);
                Log.i("Yolo", realPath);
                MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mmr.setDataSource(realPath);

                mEditArtist
                        .setText(mmr
                                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
                mEditTitle
                        .setText(mmr
                                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Here is the Method to resolve the file path

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
                null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to resolve the pathes, as i get the IllegalArgumentException

As I am selecting different files in different locations I get several errors. Here is one of them (choosing file with root brwoser on SD card)

```
11-05 02:09:45.323: E/AndroidRuntime(14575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131073, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT dat=file:///storage/sdcard1/Sounds/Camo & Krooked/Cross The Line (Special Edition)-2011/[01] [Camo & Krooked] - Get Dirty (Feat. TC).mp3 cmp=com.jrummy.root.browserfree/com.jrummy.file.manager.FilePicker }} to activity {com.example.sharefrogg/com.example.sharefrogg.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Did you add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your manifest: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: Yes. I also tried reading different file from internal stroage but I can't read it as well